# Web API routing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get a test application running using MVC WEB API but i can't get it work.
What i want to do is send a GET request and as an answer get log records from a database as response.

Here's what i've set up:

Global.asax.cs: (unmodified)

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

my controller is called DBModelController:

```
 public class DBModelController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Log> GetAllLogs()
    {
        IDBModel DAO = new DBModelDAO();

        IList<Log> Logs = DAO.GetLogs(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now); //this gives back Log objects

        return Logs;
    }

}
```

and how i want it to use:

http://localhost:15339/api/logs     --and in return i get back a set of serialized records

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class to LogsController

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route if you are not interested to change the controller class name into `Logs`.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "log_route",
    routeTemplate: "api/logs",
    defaults: new { controller = "DBModel", action = "GetAllLogs" }
);
```

This route should be placed before the default routes.